# Hibernate mapping internal class, Error "Could not determine type for: timeStamps"

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jpa

I have Entity "Task" that needs to have an internal component called "timestamps" that holds values for when the task was submitted, started and completed.

```
@Entity
public class Task {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer Id;
    private String Status;
    private Timestamps timestamps;
    // getters setters
}
```

Then I created the Timestamps class

```
public class Timestamps {
 private Timestamp submitted;
 private Timestamp started;
 private Timestamp completed;
 //getter and setters
}
```

How do I make this mapping so when I retrieve the information in JSON format I have something like this?

```
# task
{
    "task": # ASCII string
    "status": # one of "submitted", "started", "completed"
    "timestamps": {
    "submitted": # unix/epoch time
    "started": # unix/epoch time or null if not started
    "completed": # unix/epoch time or null if not completed
    }
}
```

Comment: @Spara It does not work: I got "No identifier specified for entity: com.tasks.Timestamps"

Comment: If you don't want to persist Timestamps in database you can use `@Transient`. If you want to persits Timestamps as a relation in DB you should make it as entity with an identifier then a `@ManyToOne` relation with task enitity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the @Embeddable annotation on Timestamps. Hibernate will map the fields as columns in the same table. 
You might also need an @Embedded on the Timestamps field in Task (I cant remeber for certain if both sides need an annotation).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to persist `Timestamps` in DB and just use it In DTO This will helps you:

`@Transient` annotation is used to indicate that a field is not to be persisted in the database.

```
@Entity
public class Task {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer Id;
private String Status;
@Transient
private Timestamps timestamps;
// getters setters
}
```

---

If you want to persist `Timestamps` as a relation you should do something like this:

```
@Entity
public class Timestamps {
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private Integer Id;
 private Timestamp submitted;
 private Timestamp started;
 private Timestamp completed;
 //getter and setters
}

@Entity
public class Task {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer Id;
private String Status;
@ManyToOne
private Timestamps timestamps;
// getters setters
}
```

Comment: It kind of works. However, I would like to have the timestamps to persist in the database as columns of task. The annoying thing is that I need to make the JSON in that particular format.